# How to keep updating the displayed route obtained through Google Directions API as user moves towards the destination?

Tags: android, google-maps, optimization, geolocation, google-directions-api

I obtained driving directions to a destination in my Android app. Now as the user progresses towards the destination on this route, I want to hide the portion of the route already covered and update the remaining distance. Also, if the users strays from the route that is currently being displayed, I want to recalculate the driving directions to the destination from the user's new location.

Can anyone suggest how I should approach this? Should I keep searching for user's location coordinates in the calculated route or is there a better way of doing this?